# How to load a multiline setting from a file using bash?

Tags: php, bash, sed, grep, cat

I have a long config file which looks like:

```
<some stuff before our example>
    'Realtime' => [
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'enabled' => true,
        'lorem' => 'ipsum'
    ],
<some stuff after our example>
```

The above is a large config php file and I was asked to mine the `enabled` value of 'Realtime` with bash. I could do it with PHP, but I was specifically asked to do it with bash.

I tried the following:

```
echo $(tr '\n' ' ' < myconfig.php | sed '$s/ $/\n/') | grep -o -P '(?<=Realtime).*(?=\])'
```

and this mines the text from the file between `Realtime` **and the last** `]`. But I would like to mine the content between `Realtime` and the first `]`. For the time being I have implemented a simplistic bash and accompanied that with PHP parser, as follows:

```
    public function getConfig($name)
    {
        $path = Paths::CONFIG_FILE;
        if (!$this->config) {
            $this->config = Command_ShellFactory::makeForServer('zl', "cat {$path}")->execute(true, true);
        }
        $splitName = explode('.', $name);
        $lastPosition = 0;
        $tempConfig = $this->config;
        foreach ($splitName as $currentName) {
            if (($position = strpos($tempConfig, $currentName)) === false) {
                throw new RuntimeException('Setting was not found');
            }

            $tempConfig = substr($tempConfig, $position);
        }

        return trim(explode("=>", explode("\n", $tempConfig)[0])[1], ", \n\r\t\v\x00");
    }
```

and this works, but I'm not satisfied with it, because it loads the whole file into memory via the shell command and then searches for the nested key (`Realtime.enabled` is passed to it). Is it possible to improve this code in such a way that all the logic would happen via bash, rather than helping it with PHP?

EDIT

The possible settings to mine could be of any depth. Examples:

```
[
    /*...*/
    'a' => 'b', //Depth of 1
    'c' => [
        'a' => 'd' //Depth of 2
    ],
    'e' => [
        'f' => [
            'g' =>'h' //Depth of 3
        ]
    ]
    /*...*/
]
```

Theoretically any amount of depth is possible, in the example we have a depth of 1, a depth of 2 and a depth of 3.

EDIT

I have created foo.sh (some fantasy name of no importance):

```
[
    'Realtime' => [
        'enabled' => [
            'd' => [
                'e' => 'f'
            ],
        ],
        'a' => [
            'b' => 'c'
        ],
    ]
    'g' => [
        'h' => 'i'
    ],
    'Unrealtime' => 'abc'
]
```

Working one-dimensional command:

```
sed -Ez ":a;s/.*Unrealtime' => +([^,]*).*/\1\n/" foo.sh | head -1
```

The result is

> 'abc'

Working two-dimensional command:

```
sed -Ez ":a;s/.*g[^]]*h' => +([^,]*).*/\1\n/" foo.sh | head -1
```

The result is

> 'i'

Three-dimensional command:

```
sed -Ez ":a;s/.*Realtime*[^]]*a[^]]*b' => +([^,]*).*/\1\n/" foo.sh | head -1
```

It is working if and only if the

```
    'a' => [
        'b' => 'c'
    ]
```

is the first child of `Realtime`. So, something is missing, as I need to avoid assuming that the element I search for is the first child.

Working four-dimensional command:

```
sed -Ez ":a;s/.*Realtime[^]]*enabled[^]]*d[^]]*e' => +([^,]*).*/\1\n/" foo.sh | head -1
```

Again, it only works if `enabled` is the first child of `Realtime`. I was modifying my test case above, changing the order of the children of `Realtime`. So, it seems that the only thing missing from this expression is something that would specify that we are not necessarily looking for the first child.

Comment: It seems counter-productive to parse PHP data with bash. Why were you given that requirement?

Comment: @glennjackman it is counter-intuitive and I have no idea why the client wants it like this. I have a working solution, but I think it's not very elegant.

Comment: looking at the latest update ... what's the expected result if someone asks for `e -> f`? do you return the sub-section/array - `[ 'g' => 'h' ]`? do you return nothing? something else?

Comment: Aside: Why do you use  `cat` instead of `file_get_contents($path)`?

Comment: The example with the varying depths isn't clear; what would be `RealTime` and `enabled` in them?

Comment: @markp-fuso e -> f is an unreasonable expectation. e -> f -> g would be asked for in that case.

Comment: @Fravadona because I was specifically asked in the ticket to load it with CLI. The file is also on another Docker container.

Comment: @Fravadona the first item would be asked for by specifying `a`. The second would be asked for by specifying `c.a`. The third would be asked for by specifying `e.f.g`. `Realtime` and `enabled` has a depth of two, so it resembles the second example the most.

Comment: assuming it's not possible to get the source file (re)formatted in a common format (eg, json, yaml, xml), which could be processed by an appropriate tool (eg, jq, yq, xmllint), it seems (to me) you're left with writing a custom parser; unfortunately, delving into any (detailed) discussions on the design of a parser would fall outside the scope of this site (stackoverlow)

Comment: @markp-fuso HatLess's solution is very very close to a full solution. I do not know yet how I could add or remove dimensions from it due to my limited bash knowledge, but I've almost got it working for three dimensions. The other two answers are also of high-caliber.

Comment: @markp-fuso I have got to the point of `echo "'Realtime' => ['enabled' => ['d' => ['e' => 'f']], 'a' => ['b' => 'c']]" | sed -Ez ":a;s/.*Realtime[^]]*enabled[^]]*d[^]]*e' => +([^,]*).*/\1\n/"` which is very very close to what I'm looking for. It results in `'f']]` so something has to be done with the unnecessary `]]` at the end, but I cannot simply remove it because in some cases that might be part of the value.

Comment: @LajosArpad Apologies, my wife dragged me away from the screen to have dinner. Going by your code above, you can do `sed -Ez "s/.*Realtime[^]]*enabled[^]]*d[^]]*e'
 => +'?([^,']*).*/\1\n/"` to remove `]]`, however, I am yet to try and tackle your new sample.

Comment: @HatLess I'm going to have the exact same fate as you (with wife and dinner), but I've got it working and left a comment at your answer. If you edit your answer with the code which was working for me (or something better, then I will accept your answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the string `Realtime` occurs only once in the file, you can try this GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez "s/.*Realtime[^]]*enabled' => +([^,]*).*/\1\n/" myconfig.php
true
```

**EDIT**

Working code for OP's use case

```
$ sed -Ez "s/.*Realtime*[^]]*[^[]*a[^]]*b' => +([^,]*).*/\1\n/" foo.sh | head -1
```

Comment: This is absolutely great! How could I do this with arbitrary length? How would this change if I had to find the value of enabled inside an array called Realtime inside an array of Setting?

Comment: Also, how would this be modified if Realtime was a single value (not an array)?

Comment: @LajosArpad Can you provide a sample of the array in question?

Comment: Example1: `[/*..., */ 'a' => ['b' => ['c' => 'd']] /*, ...*/]`, where I would search for the value of c, inside b inside a. Example2: `[/*..., */ 'a' => 'b'] /*, ...*/]` where I would search for the value of a. Both cases are similar to the one you have implemented with the difference that you have implemented it for a depth of 2, while the depth could be 1, 3 or more as well. I'm happy to handle the logic, but I do not know yet how this command has to change in such scenarios.

Comment: Tried with `echo "'Realtime' => ['enabled' => ['d' => 'e'], 'a' => ['b' => 'c']]" | sed -Ez ":a;s/.*Realtime[^]]*enabled[^]]*d' => +([^,]*).*/\1\n/"` the result is `'e']`

Comment: If I add a further dimension with `echo "'Realtime' => ['enabled' => ['d' => ['e' => 'f']], 'a' => ['b' => 'c']]" | sed -Ez ":a;s/.*Realtime[^]]*enabled[^]]*d[^]]*e' => +([^,]*).*/\1\n/"` then the result is `f]]`. So, something is keeping an additional `]` in the result for each dimension starting from depth = 3

Comment: @LajosArpad Example1 `sed -Ez "s/.*b[^]]*c' => +'?([^,']*).*/\1\n/"`  Example2 `sed -Ez "s/[^]]*a' => +'?([^,']*).*/\1\n/"` Note that your initial sample did not have a quote before `true`

Comment: It may or may not have a quote before the value. In the case of a boolean we do not have a quote, but it could be a string. Looking into your examples.

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes, I have considered that in the code

Comment: `sed -Ez "s/.*b[^]]*c' => +'?([^,']*).*/\1\n/"` works, but it's unsafe. I could have similar inner keys. Is there a way to tell it that I'm looking for the c child of the b child of a?

Comment: @LajosArpad Potentially, but we are using a greedy regex which will not allow it and would require a rework of the code. If possible, add another sample to your question showing these potential pitfalls and I'll see if I can construct a work around code.

Comment: I have edited my question, added an example containing elements of depth of 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Got it working. If I do a `sed -Ez ":a;s/.*Realtime[^]]*enabled[^]]*d[^]]*e' => +([^,]*).*/\1\n/" foo.sh | head -1`, it works, assuming that the `[` and `]` characters are not in the same line as the content

Comment: @LajosArpad Your code piped to `head` still seems to leave the tailing brackets, at least for me. I think the answer I provided in the comments is a better fit, however, I do not have your real data to work with so if the solution works for you, that is great and I am happy to have helped. However, as it does not work with your provided sample, I think I will leave the code that does work. These comments can be read if future readers have a similar issue.

Comment: Found some possible inputs when my adjustment is still not working. Edited my question with further details.

Comment: @LajosArpad Three dimensional `sed -Ez "s/.*Realtime*[^]]*[^[]*a[^]]*b' => +([^,]*).*/\1\n/" foo.sh | head -1` BTW, you can remove the label at the start of the code `:a;`, it is not needed as I did not loop which I intended to do

Comment: Three-dimensional: `sed -Ez "s/.*Realtime*[^]]*[^[]*a[^]]*b' => +([^,]*).*/\1\n/" foo.sh | head -1`, four-dimensional: `sed -Ez "s/.*Realtime*[^]]*[^[]*enabled[^]]*d[^]]*e' => +([^,]*).*/\1\n/" foo.sh | head -1`.I will try to understand this before adjusting my code in order to generate this, but since this appears to work on all test cases, I'm happy to accept your answer if you edit it with this information.

Comment: Even if OP is fine with the results, you should mention the limitations of your solution: GNU sed specific, characters in values and unrelated keys can contribute to the match, the match isn't anchored to the root, if a prior sibling is an array then the match fails, etc... An ERE is a bad fit for this task, you need at least a more advanced regex engine like PCRE.

Comment: @Fravadona It is mentioned that this is `GNU`, maybe read it again. Further, I did not provide the accepted solution, OP did, I just provided the framework that OP wanted to be added to my answer. You have been complaining about my solution for close to 24 hours despite the presence of more robust solutions, yet, my solution seemed to fit OP's needs more, so maybe bring your grievances up with OP in the comments as you had done before removing it to air your grievances here.

Comment: Sorry for the GNU mention, I really didn't see it. You're right, I do have some grievance against OP way of not understanding the ins and out of his question, but my comment is unrelated to that: Basically, OP's asking to write a PHP-aware shell script, which most probably will get tons of views in the future, but your answer doesn't mention it's limitations. Just one or two examples of what can go wrong would be enough to show people that "Huh, it's not so simple". Cheers

Answer (score 2):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F"'" '                                             # define input field delimiter as single quote
$2 == "Realtime"           { inblock=1 }                # if 2nd field == "Realtime" then set flag
$2 == "enabled" && inblock { if (NF==3) {               # value is not wrapped in single quotes
                                pos=index($0,"=>")      # find location of "=>" string
                                value=substr($0,pos+2)  # grab everything after "=>"
                                gsub(/[ ,]/,"",value)   # remove all spaces and commas
                             }
                             else                       # value is wrapped in single quotes
                                value=$4                # grab 4th field
                             print value
                             exit                       # no need to process rest of file so exit script
                           }
' myconfig.php
```

This generates:

```
true
```

**NOTE:** this solution is hardcoded based on provided sample

Comment: This works properly, but I do not understand it, unfortunately, bash is not my main strength. Can you explain this solution?

Comment: @LajosArpad added some comments; technically this isn't `bash`; `awk` is a binary that's generally available under quite a few shells ... `bash`, `sh`, `dash`, etc

Comment: The problem is that I cannot apply this solution if I don't understand it, because I may have different depths. It could be a simple setting of the form of 'foo' => 'bar', but it could be a setting inside a setting inside a setting... For now we need this for the single example I have described, but I'm trying to implement a more general solution.

Comment: @LajosArpad For a general solution you'll have to write a PHP parser...

Comment: @Fravadona I'm happy to generate the command via PHP, but I need to understand the command well in order to be able to implement a generator for it.

Comment: this is the standard problem with a (quick-n-dirty) solution that addresses a specific, single format vs a solution that addresses a more flexible, variable format; while an `awk` solution may be possible (for the flexible/variable format) it will basically come down to writing the equivalent of a parser ... doable but (in my case - PHP ignorant) would need more examples of what you're dealing with ... and would likely get as complicated/lengthy as your current `getConfig()` solution

Comment: @markp-fuso the problem with my solution is not that it's too complicated. The problem is that I have a PHP parser after the cat. Instead I would need a single CLI command and I would be happy to implement the PHP that generates it, complicated or not. But in order to be able to implement it, I need to understand how this looks alike if the depth is 3 (if I know that I will be able to easily deduce how it would look alike at greater depths) and how it looks alike with a depth of 1. I'm providing you examples in the next comment.

Comment: Example1: [/*..., */ 'a' => ['b' => ['c' => 'd']] /*, ...*/], where I would search for the value of c, inside b inside a. Example2: [/*..., */ 'a' => 'b'] /*, ...*/] where I would search for the value of a

Comment: fwif, don't add examples to comments; add the additional examples to the question

Comment: updated answer to address issue where value may or may not be wrapped in single quotes (eg, `true` vs `'bar ipsum'`); (still) does not address a variable depth for the search

Comment: I have removed your edit from the question, because, even though `'a' => 'g'` is possible, it is not necessary to have an `'a'` leaf.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your test with `tr` and `grep`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

tr -d "\n" < "myconfig.php" \
| grep -o "'Realtime' => \[[^\]*\]" \
| grep -oE "'enabled' => (true|false)" \
| head -1 \
| cut -d " " -f 3
```

Notes:

- If you have only one `Realtime` block in your file, `| head -1` if not necessary
- If you are not sure about number of spaces, remove all spaces and changes next filters like this:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

tr -d "\n" < "myconfig.php" \
| tr -d " " \
| grep -o "'Realtime'=>\[[^\]*\]" \
| grep -oE "'enabled'=>(true|false)" \
| head -1 \
| cut -d ">" -f 2
```

### UPDATE

More generic solution:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

INPUT_FILE="$1"
LEVEL_1_OBJ="Settings"
LEVEL_N_OBJ="Realtime"
FIELD="enabled"

tr -d "\n" < "${INPUT_FILE}" \
| tr -d " " \
| grep -o "'${LEVEL_1_OBJ}'=>\[.*" \
| grep -o "'${LEVEL_N_OBJ}'=>\[[^\]*\]" \
| grep -oE "'${FIELD}'=>[^,]*" \
| head -1 \
| cut -d ">" -f 2
```

You cloud add level filter between 1 and N (the last) and/or any filter between each `grep` commands

Comment: Excellent! If this was a nested array, so I would search for the `Settings` array, inside which I would search for `Realtime` array, inside which I would search for `enabled`, how would this change?

Comment: Change first `grep` by `| grep -o "'Settings'=>\[.*'Realtime'=>\[[^\]*\]" \ ` (in second code block)

Comment: I see! Let me try. Thanks!

Comment: If doesn't work, please update you request with an example

Comment: I have edited my question accordingly.